# Which one to go first, Grails or Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I wanted to create a web application. I thought of selecting Groovy or Grails. But I don't know from where to start! To start with Groovy or Grails?

Comment: This mostly depends on *your* goals, expectations, and learning style. In any case, "just do it" and have fun. (A tutorial and/or good book is usually recommended -- I'm sure both the Grails and Groovy sites will help here).

Comment: Groovy is a language, Grails is a framework. You need to learn Groovy to get the most out of Grails. Start your learning at grails.org via the user guide and samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I've just been in the same situation.*

With my last Java experiences dating back some 7 years, I *tried* to start with Grails directly using "[The Definitive Guide to Grails](http://www.amazon.de/Definitive-Guide-Grails-Experts-Development/dp/1590599950)".

I went about 1/3rd thru and thought I understood enough to start out. But as soon as I started to hack I noticed I simply ran into *too many errors that would take me hours to resolve*, simply because of **missing Groovy knowledge**.

So I went and got myself "[Groovy in Action](http://www.amazon.de/Groovy-Action-Dierk-Konig/dp/1932394842/)" (*a.k.a GinA*). I studied the whole book and programmed each and every listing myself. As I didn't focus on this task solely, it took me several weeks to complete the 600+ pages.

Then I went back to my Grails project and *found that I had even forgotten the things I already had known* from the first book.

**In hindsight, I would go about the task like this:**

Directly start your Grails project (I recommend you setup <del>[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)</del> <del>[SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/landing/best-development-tool-enterprise-java)</del> [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/#ultimate) as your IDE)

1. **Work on it** every day for about one
   hour
2. **Learn ~50 pages** in your
   preferred **Groovy** resource.
3. **Learn ~20 pages** in your preferred
   **Grails** resource.
4. **Apply** what you
   learned

Keep in mind that the current edition of *Groovy in Action* is dated 2007 and *The Definitive Guide to Grails* is dated 2009.

In both cases this is quite old, though almost all of the *GinA* examples still work.

The most important parts of the official *Grails Framework Reference* are written well structured in chapters, thus it will suite perfectly as your Grails resource.

**The following combination would be my personal choice:**

- **Groovy:** [Groovy in Action, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/) as [MEAP (Manning Early
  Access Program)](http://www.manning.com/about/meap.html) *($34.99 or $49.99)*
- **Grails:** [The Grails Framework - Reference Documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/) *(free)*

I'd love to hear about your success & subscribed to your questions as I might be able to help with some of your simpler ones.

Enjoy!

Comment: I would avoid Netbeans. Since the oracle buyout, nothing has been added to groovy or grails, and support is now woeful. Try STS, IDEA or Eclipse with the relevant plugin for proper, current, support for the language and framework

Comment: Ya thanks for the "nice" answer by user569825!!!

Comment: Note that, after having accumulated a lot of experience with Grails, I advise against using the framework at all. There's a good post (in German) at http://groovy-skills.com/Grails/2012/08/19/ultimativer-showdown-grails-vs-rails/ which, besides providing a comparison to Rails, points out some of the gravest annoyances of Grails.

Answer (score 7):

If you know Java, go directly to grails. Groovy can be used with pure Java syntax, and you'll be learning its special syntax extras on the way.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that you're misunderstanding what exactly Groovy and Grails are.

**Groovy** is a **dynamic language** that uses Java's JVM (virtual machine). It can compile to Java bytecode and run anywhere that a typical Java program can run. It's *only* a language, not a framework for developing web applications. You *could* use Groovy by itself to build a web application, leveraging Servlets, JSPs, and other libraries to help you. However...

**Grails** is a **framework** that *uses* the Groovy language to help you build web applications. Grails gives you easy ways to create all of the web application components that you'd normally have to build yourself (using Servlets, JSPs, etc.).

This may help explain to you *why* [Bozho suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766161/which-one-to-go-first-grails-or-groovy/4766916#4766916) to go straight to Grails (and why I agree with him).

Comment: According to this tweet: @aalmiray: every time someone says "Groovy is just a scripting solution for Java" a puppy dies - a puppy just died... :-)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'll change 'scripting' to 'dynamic'. I was only doing my best to make a concise definition for the OP. :)

Comment: Cool. The puppy just came alive again :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the opportunity to deploy on google appengine you should take a look at Gaelyk (http://gaelyk.appspot.com/), which is a Groovy framework that gets you up and running realy fast.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your situation, I would start with grails. Here is the Quick Start tutorial: http://grails.org/Quick+Start

At some point you may want something lighter. When that happens check out Ratpack at https://github.com/bleedingwolf/Ratpack#readme

Comment: My pleasure. :)  Please check the answer you like best.

Answer (score 0):

As a learner like you, here is what I've got in few last weeks.

Even if you're familiar with Java, Grails auto-generates templates of code, and knowing Groovy syntax helps to understand it better.

I very suggest books by Scott Davis, they are just brilliant -- short, clear, and straightforward.
Start from "Groovy Recipes", and then take a look at "Getting Started with Grails".

Gaelyk is good for some very custom webapps, but if you're doing ordinary dynamic website, then too much code has to be written manually, and from scratch. Grails provides much more help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know Groovy or Java, sure, you could go straight to Grails, although much of it will be  lost on you.  My path has been Grails, Groovy, Grails, and now Groovy full-time.

Groovy provides so much pure goodness (builders, command chaining, closure driven Annotations, Groovy SQL, POGOs, etc.), it would be a shame not to explore it in depth ;--)

I'll get back to Grails no doubt, but I am having too much fun with Groovy right now...